# How do I keep my right hand navigation fixed? (so that it won't change when browser is resized)

Tags: html, css, navigation

I've looked up a few solutions - but with my css it doesn't seem to work :/
Here is my css:

```
#mainNav {  
    right: 0;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70%;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -10px;      
    display: inline-block;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase:

}




#mainNav li{
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px 8px 0px 0px;
    position:relative;

    }


#mainnav ul{
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px 8px 0px 0px;

}
#mainnav ul li{

   color: #000;
}
#mainNav li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
    background-color:#efefef;
    font-size:10pt; 
    color: #4f5052;
}



#mainNav li a:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #91877e;

    }

#mainNav li a:active{
    color:#91877e;

    }

li a:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #91877e;

}
```

I have tried position fixed - it just cuts off half of my navigation even when I change around top etc. If anyone has any simple solutions or anything that will help please post :D Thank you.

HTML

```
 <div id="mainnav">
    <ul>

  <li><a href="/"><strong>Home</strong></a></li><font color="#91877e"<font size=3></font></color>
         <li><a href="/mind/"> Investment</a><font color="#91877e"<font size=3></font></color>
        <li><a href="/body/">Rentals</a></li><font color="#91877e"<font size=3></font></color>
        <li><a href="/soul/">About</a><font color="#91877e"<font size=3></font></color>
        <li><a href="/soul/">Contact</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML too??

Comment: please include you html in your question.

Comment: Added html! Sorry - didn't think about that!

Comment: Why you don't style your HTML using ONLY CSS? (why do you use strong, font, color tags?) And also there are unusable tags in your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `HTML` code there were some unusable `tags` and also in your provided `CSS` I've found that you used `#mainNav` selector instead of `#mainnav`. Here is the working version of your code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2h6h/2/). Note, that I've added example text in order to have a `scrollbar`.